# How to get all items to a string [] from listview?

Tags: c#

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = @".\ext.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
int i=0;
string item = listView1.Items[i++].Text;
startInfo.Arguments = "--logfile=duration_output.txt " + (item);
```

I am trying to list all items as a `string[]`, but then the application gives me an empty logfile.
When I use the simple `string item = listView1.Items[i++].Text`, it gives me only one the first file on the output.

How is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
startInfo.Arguments = "--logfile=duration_output.txt " +
    string.Join(" ", from item in listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                     select @"""" + item.Text + @""""
               );
```

Comment: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection'.  'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'item'.

Comment: @user830054: then you must only have 4 items in your list view. Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: WinForms and when I have 20-30 items selects 4, when less selects nothing, only gaves me a blank txt.

Comment: Ok I know why recognizes only a few items: when file or path has a space in the name it skips.

Comment: :( No it's not working well. When I use more than 300 files it don't recognize all of them

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over all the items in the listview and concatenate them into a single string:

```
string item = string.Empty;
foreach (ListViewItem anItem in listView1.Items)
{
  item += " " & anItem.Text;
}
```

Comment: object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string[] items = listView1.Items.Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
```

Comment: "There is no "Select" method."

Comment: You need to make sure you have `using System.Linq;` at the top of your class.

Comment: @user830054: It does not have it because [ListViewItemCollection does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.aspx).

Comment: I mean I added System.Linq at the begining

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder args = new StringBuilder();
args.Append("--logfile=duration_output.txt");
foreach( var str in listView1.Items )
{
    args.Append( " " );
    args.Append( str );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

//here is something you can use getting directly at System.Diagnostics
// it works just replace Console.WriteLine with what ever Stream Class you are using.
//Replace where I use System.Diagnostics with ListView Iterate thru the listview itesm

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process[] proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach(Process theprocess in proc)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
    }
```